# How to resolve "return" outside function error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
phone_letters =[" ", "1", "ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO","PQRS","TUV","WXYZ","*","0","#" ]
key = 0
string = input("Enter a Letter: ",)

while key < 10 :
        if string in phone_letters[key]: 
            print(key)
            return key
        else:
            key = key+1

        return "not found"
```

I am getting error `'return' outside function`; I checked indentation and still the error continues.

Comment: You don't seem to have a function at all, so it shouldn't be surprising that the `return` statement isn't in one. Read about functions: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions

Answer (score 1):

> `return` may only occur syntactically nested in a function definition

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement

Your return is not nested inside a function. Therefore, the error.

You can use `print("not found")` if you want to display the text.